# Заполнение list view sub item

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, есть компонент listview заполненный при помощи адаптера из файла strings.xml, как сделать так чтобы пункты sub item находящиеся снизу заполнялись таким же образом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**код активити**

```
public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] arr;
    ListView listView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Comment: Вам надо свой адаптер написать)

Comment: а как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо свою разметку использовать для ячейки списка, в которой будет 2 текстовых поля. Для этого надо переопределить в своей реализации адаптера метод `getView()`, в котором загрузить свою разметку, наполнить её данными и отобразить. Правильный способ - это вообще через `RecyclerView` это делать, т.к. он сразу с `ViewHolder` и вообще более гибкий, но вот вам более простой и быстрый способ. Но я не гарантирую что он будет компилироваться/работать.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr) {

  // пункт списка
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     View view = LayoutInflayter.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

     ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(arr[position]);
     ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText(arr[position]);

    return view;
  }

};
```

Ну и надо свой файл разметки под это дело с именем `item`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Описанное выше не факт что работает и крайне неправильно и я очень не советую это использовать - но это самый простой способ свою разметку впервые отобразить.

Усложнение примера тут: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html

А вообще -  читайте про RecyclerView

Comment: для разметки, как на скриншоте есть  системная разметка `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`, биндить туда контент можно системным же `SimpleAdapter`, без необходимости кастомного адаптера